# Is there a good R function for separating unique column values between two data frames, keeping rows?

Tags: r, dataframe

basically I have 2 data frames with this basic structure:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 12 | xxx | 32b |
| tfe | 21 | xxx | 14f |
| eed | 12 | xxx | 54b |
| wes | 95 | xxx | 54r |
| rtf | 44 | xxx | 99q |
| fvg | 87 | xxx | 55h |

So some of the values in column 1 are repeated in both data frames and I wanted to make a new data frame with only the rows with unique values in Col1 for each dataframe, so in psuedo-code:

Unique_to_df1 <- df1[Unique_Function(find rows with Col1 values not in df2)]
Unique_to_df2 <- df2[Unique_Function(find rows with Col1 values not in df1)]

I have tried a few functions, but they all either seem to only export the unique values of Col1, not the whole table or only seem to work with removing.extracting duplicate values from one data frame, not comparing between two. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at `setdiff`

Comment: Like an inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setdiff` to select *rows with unique values in Col1 for each dataframe*.

```
x[x$Col1 %in% setdiff(x$Col1, y$Col1),]
#x[!x$Col1 %in% intersect(x$Col1, y$Col1),] #Alternative
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1  aaa   12  xxx  32b

y[y$Col1 %in% setdiff(y$Col1, x$Col1),]
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#1  bbb   12  xxx  32b
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Col1     Col2    Col3    Col4
aaa     12  xxx     32b
tfe     21  xxx     14f
eed     12  xxx     54b
wes     95  xxx     54r
rtf     44  xxx     99q
fvg     87  xxx     55h")
y <- x
y[1,1] <- "bbb"
```

Answer (score 1):

`anti_join(x, y)` drops all observations in x that have a match in y.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Col1 = c("aaa", "tfe", "eed", "wes", "rtf", "fvg"),
              Col2 = c(12L, 21L, 12L, 95L, 44L, 87L),
              Col3 = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
              Col4 = c("32b", "14f", "54b", "54r", "99q", "55h")
)


df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Col1 = c("a", "tfe", "ee", "ws", "rt", "fvg"),
              Col2 = c(12L, 21L, 12L, 95L, 44L, 87L),
              Col3 = c("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx"),
              Col4 = c("32b", "14f", "54b", "54r", "99q", "55h")
)

library(dplyr)

unique1 <- df1 %>% 
  anti_join(df2)

unique2 <- df2 %>% 
  anti_join(df1)


# Join them together:

rbind(unique1, unique2)

#>   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
#> 1  aaa   12  xxx  32b
#> 2  eed   12  xxx  54b
#> 3  wes   95  xxx  54r
#> 4  rtf   44  xxx  99q
#> 5    a   12  xxx  32b
#> 6   ee   12  xxx  54b
#> 7   ws   95  xxx  54r
#> 8   rt   44  xxx  99q
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>